# Excel If/Then Formula

Tags: excel, math, logic

so I need help with a very simple if/then statement in Excel. 
I was never very good at coding...so here I am.

I have a column that includes attendance for an event. If a cell in this column (lets say A1) reaches the number 8, I need the cell next to it (B1) to increase by 1. If "A1" reaches 16, I need (A2) to increase to 2. ...and so on for multiples of 8.

I'm sure it's very simple, but I'm new to working with equations in Excel, so any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: You want B1 to count the multiples of 8 in A1?  Then the formula you want is `=Quotient(A1,8)`

Comment: In cell B1, use this formula: `=INT(A1/8)` Note that the formula will only work if A1 is a number and will return an error if A1 is text.

Answer (score 1):

You want a simple formula like:

```
= ROUNDDOWN(A1/8, 0)
```

For B1

Comment: The ROUNDDOWN works perfectly in my situation. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If column A has all the attendance figures [1,2,3,4,5...etc] then in column B2 enter the formula:

=if(mod(a1,8)=0,B1+1,B1)

Drag this down through the rest of column B for all values in column A

Mod(a1,8) returns the remainder of A1 / 8. If it's divisible by 8 the remainder will be 0. Since you want a count, we can keep it in column B and just add 1 to the previous value.